# How to return corresponding rows of duplicate iterations of a value - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an xlsx file that contains 20 columns and hundreds of rows. I want to use a function similar to Xlookup in Excel, but want to return duplicate values as well. For example, if the first column is names and there are 63 unique "Ben", I would like to return the entire row's data for all of the "Ben" iterations in the first column.

I already have numpy,scipy,pandas, and can install other libraries that may be necessary to conduct this function.

Is there any way to do this in Python or even Excel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
df.loc[df['Column with Ben in it'] == 'Ben'
```

If you provide more detail on your excel file it would also help in providing more assistance for your question.